# are out there token_get_all variations?

Tags: java, php, actionscript-3, token

I am wondering if there exists a [token_get_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) method in Actionscript like PHP does have?

Further thinking,
I am wondering if there are different versions of such function in any languages used for web developing. Such as `token_get_all_html()`, `token_get_all_cpp()`, that will split the input of HTML/C++/Java/PHP into tokens.

Thank You,
Pentium10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionScript has no such method, you would need to implement your own, Sorry!

**EDIT:** you might find something in this Eval library though: http://eval.hurlant.com/ (but I'm not sure)

Comment: I will check it out. I would want to use for a syntax highlighter.